# show loader till whole page is loaded completely in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have gridview in which there are 700 rows.I have put ajax loader on page as in this [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-loading-image-while-PostBack-calls-in-ASPNet.aspx).The loader vanishes when there are still 2-3 minutes to load data completely.I want to show loader till page loads completely. How can I achieve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              function ShowProgress() {

                  setTimeout(function () {
                      var modal = $('<div />');
                      modal.addClass("modal");
                      $('body').append(modal);
                      var loading = $(".loading");
                      loading.show();
                      var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                      var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                      loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
                  }, 1000);
              }

              $(document).ready(function () {
                  $('#Button1').click(function () {
                      ShowProgress();
                  });
              });
          </script>
<style type="text/css">
    .modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .loading
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: White;
        z-index: 999;
    }

</style>
<div class="loading" align="center">
    Loading. Please wait.<br />
    <br />
    <img src="loader.gif" alt="" />

</div>
```

Comment: use `.done` function

Comment: There is no ajax call.loader is shown on button click event on client side

Comment: Then how is the data for the grid populated? How do you know that the grid data is binded successfully? What grid are you using? You can use the grid bind event to remove loading

Answer (score 1):

Call the loader function before ajax request is sent and hide the loader once response is received or in your case data is bind to gridview.

```
displayLoader();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: url
    }).done(function (data) {
        //call is successful
        hideLoader();
    }).fail(function () {
        //call has failed
        hideLoader();
    }).always(function () {
        //always execute despite failure/success
        hideLoader();
    });
```

Comment: You should call `hideLoader()` only in `.always()` event, since always is _always_ called regardless the Ajax call is done or has failed.

Comment: There is no ajax call.loader is shown on button click event on client side.I have pasted actual code in my question

Comment: @priyathapliyal, why have you tagged Ajax then?

Comment: Im so sorry.. its a mistake

Answer (score 0):

so, it take like 5-7 minutes to load completely those rows? why don't you first create a paginate with ajax? anyway, try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "yourUrl",
  contentType: "application/json",
  context: document.body
  }).done(function() {
    $(".loading").hide();
  });
```